# AngularJS Filter values which are in another array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I'm just getting started with using filters in AngularJS. What I want to do is to link compositions to products, using a simple Select-box.

In my $scope, I have an object "product", which, among other values, contains an array "technicalProducts". This array contains all compositions, which have been linked to my current product. The array "allCompositions" holds all **existing** compositions.
No, whenever a composition has been linked, I want to remove it from the Select-options. I thought the easiest way to do this was by using a filter.

Unfortunately, this won't work:

```
<select class="form-control" name="compositions" id="compositions" ng-options="composition as composition.sysName for composition in allCompositions track by composition.sysName | filter:product.technicalProducts" ng-model="selComposition"></select>
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

filter is good for your scenario here. But you have to define a custom filter because the default filter only works for simple string.

```
// input for the target collection, args for the filter condition.
angularModule.filter('testFilter', function(input, args) {
  if (!args || args = '') return input;
  return input.filter(function(item) {
    return args.indexOf(item) === -1;
  });
})
```

then use it this way:

```
ng-options="composition as composition.sysName for composition in allCompositions | testFilter: product.technicalProducts track by composition.sysName"
```

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);


app.filter('testFilter', function() {
  return function(input, args) {
    if (!args || args === '') return input;
    return input.filter(function(item) {
      return args.indexOf(item) === -1;
    });
  };
});

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.selectedItem = 2;

  $scope.testArr = [
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
  ];
  $scope.testArr2 = [
    1, 3, 5, 7
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <select ng-options="item for item in testArr | testFilter: testArr2" ng-model="selectedItem"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! Unfortunately, when I try to use this custom filter, "input" is always undefined, as if the value isn't passed correctly from the view.

Comment: @DCH I have updated my answer. there is another mistake in the expression that we should move "track by" statement to the end of the expression.

Comment: The problem described was due to the asynchronous loading of my compositions. But I'm not sure what I have to return. Returning false or true just leads to the element being added as an option to the select-list. Returning an empty String or null also leads to the element being added, even if it's already linked.

Comment: @DCH no, you have to return the filtered array. I just add sample code in the filter.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding this right now. Your sample code gives me an exception "input.filter is not a function". I guess this is because "input" is just a String.

Comment: @DCH you are right, the input should be a iterator array. wait a moment,  i'll make you a code snippet.

Comment: I think I solved it just before you posted your new comment, but thanks anyway! You helped to get me on the right track and I'll mark your post as a solution.

Comment: @DCH glad for helped. :)